# Using the cmbraces version of newpxmath in newtxmath

Tags: pdftex, newtxmath

How do I incorporate the curly `{` and `}` cmbraces version of newpxmath package into newtxmath? Both the packages do support the computer modern braces version, but newpxmath cmbraces look far more better to the eye than the newtxmath version.

I went into `newpxmath.sty` and tried using the command

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{symbols}{102}{largesymbols}{8}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace}{\mathclose}{symbols}{103}{largesymbols}{9}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @egreg: You might want to help me with this question :) as you have always done.

Comment: As far as I can see, the `cmbraces` option does nothing, with the current version of both `newtxmath` and `newpxmath`. I see no big difference between braces with `newpxmath` and `newtxmath`.

Comment: @egreg I have the older version of the `newtxmath` package. The older version does have a difference though

Answer (score 2):

You can use the standard `cmex` braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{
  <-7.5> cmex7
  <7.5-8.5> cmex8
  <8.5-9.5> cmex9
  <9.5-> cmex10
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace}{\mathclose}{symbols}{"67}{cmlargesymbols}{"09}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{symbols}{"66}{cmlargesymbols}{"08}

\begin{document}

\[
\{x\}\ne\left\{\frac{a}{b}\right\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with the standard `newtxmath` braces, that are slimmer.

[image]